# Trigger emails on business days every month excluding weekends and holidays

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, jquery, visual-studio, nintex

I am working on designing nintex workflow, I have a list which contains doc type and Frequency columns

If I had to select doc type as report and frequency as monthly, the workflow should trigger emails on 4th, 7th and 9th business days excluding holidays (United States) and weekends. I am restricted to designer and OutOfBox. Please suggest if I can achieve using OOB functionality or JQuery, JavaScript.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

By the way I am using SharePoint 2010 sites and designer